# Update pandas dataframe based on slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I wish to split into "train" and "test" datasets using the `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` function. This function returns two slices of the original DataFrame. I however need this to be in a single DataFrame, with a column entry that identifies identifies the entry type. I could write a function that does this instead, but using the sklearn function is convenient and reliable.

My current approach is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import model_selection

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD')).reset_index()

split = [0.8, 0.2]
split_seed = 123

train_df, test_df = model_selection.train_test_split(df, train_size = split[0], test_size = split[1], random_state=split_seed)

train_df["Dataset"] = "train"
test_df["Dataset"] = "test"

final_df = train_df.append(test_df)
```

This works perfectly, but results in a warning since I am modifying copied slices instead of the original `df` object:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

It doesn't really matter since the original DataFrame is no longer used after this. But I'm curious how I could do this differently. I presume that instead of editing `train_df` and `test_df` and the appending them again, I could just edit `df` directly, but as I am not very familiar with how `.loc` and `.iloc` works I'm struggling to see how this would work.

Psuedo code that illustrates what I am looking for would be as follows:

```
df["Dataset"] = "train" WHERE index in train_df.index.values
df["Dataset"] = "test" WHERE index in test_df.index.values
```

Comment: You could just call the `train_test_split` method with a `copy` of your `df`: `model_selection.train_test_split(df.copy())`, if all you want to do is avoid the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to `copy` your `DataFrame` in the `model_selection.train_test_split()` call you can use `loc`:

```
df.loc[train_df.index, 'Dataset'] = 'train'
df.loc[test_df.index, 'Dataset'] = 'test'
```

Comment: Yep, this was exactly the kind of answer i was hoping for!

Comment: happy to assist :)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `np.where` to add a series conditional on a Boolean condition:

```
df['Dataset'] = np.where(df.index.isin(train_df.index.values), 'train', 'test')
```

This assumes, of course, indices not contained in `train_df` *must* exist in `test_df`.

Or use `np.select` for a more adaptable solution:

```
conds = [df.index.isin(train_df.index.values),
         df.index.isin(test.index.values)]

df['Dataset'] = np.select(conds, ['train', 'test'], 'other')
```

Comment: This assumes that there are only indexes in `df` that will match `train_df.index` and if not `test_df.index`. Is true for OP but should be added as a caveat.

Comment: @user3471881, Agreed, have added a disclaimer.

Comment: This can be easily adapted to hold every possible scenario if use `np.select` with a `default` value representing `Not present in any df`